Stim - Adding gates to the start of the circuit
Say I have
circ = stim.Circuit()
circ.append("CX", [0,1])

Now, I want to add a Hadamard to the beginning of the circuit. My current method entails defining a new circuit
circ2 = stim.Circuit()
circ2.append("H",[0])

circ = circ2 + circ

Is there a cleaner/built-in way to do this? I don't see anything in help(stim.Circuit()).

As of version 1.13 there's no circuit.insert method, so what you have to do as a workaround is to compute the prefix circuit prefix and perform circuit = prefix + circuit.
In 1.14 there will be stim.Circuit.insert (you can use it now by installing stim~=1.14.dev). I added it because of this question; it's kinda silly it didn't exist.
